# Getting actual name of file after upload Django

Tags: python, django, file, django-models, path

I got a problem with retrieving the current name of the file. At the moment when I'm uploading file to my model with suffix.

```
    class DataUpload(models.Model):
        file_uploaded_path = models.FileField(upload_to="csv/%Y/%m/%d/")
```

The problem with that is that I can't retrive file name with suffix.
When i use

```
>> DataUpload.file_uploaded_path.path
```

I get only only path to the media root folder

> project/media/file.txt

I've tried also .name or .url, still it's not it.
I think I checked everywhere and I'm really out of ideas.

Comment: Have you set the Media File Path in setting.py?

Comment: Those are my settings: STATIC_URL = FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME + '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME + '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I finally did it. I found a note in FileFiled documentation.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to

> Note
>
> The file is saved as part of saving the model in the database, so the actual file name used on disk cannot be relied on until after the model has been saved.

So yeah, for few hours I've been trying to get name before saving model, that's why I couldn't get the real path. Read documentation guys!